# Empty response after exception filter executed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to have a global exception filter that will process exception and return customized result/message to response. On client side I have a global ajax error function that processes all errors on each ajax call.

The problem is when an error is thrown somewhere in my application the global exception filter gets called and I try to create some custom response, but after that, when the page is rendered, on client side the response is empty (alert outputs the response).

Important thing is that I tried to use Global.asax "Application_Error" event and the response works.
Why is that? What earases my response? How can I make it work?

**Global exception filter** (response text is empty on client side):

```
public class ExceptionAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //I need to clear response so that I don't have yellow screen of death
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("OnException - Response");

       //this doesn't work too
       filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = "OnException - JSON" };

       //doesn't help
       filterContext.HttpContext.Server.ClearError();
     }
}
```

**Global.asax error handler** (response shows up on client side):

```
protected override void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write("Application_Error Test");
}
```

**Client side global ajax handler:**

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, xhr, settings, exception) {

    event.stopPropagation();

    if (xhr != null) {

        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;` (or `Server.ClearError();`)

Comment: If I use "filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;" then my global ajax error handler on client side will not be called, instead the calling function will be executed.

Comment: "Server.ClearError();" - didn't help.

Comment: @summerbabe: Set `filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;`, then set `Response.StatusCode`.

Comment: `filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;` and `Response.StatusCode` - worked! I will mark your answer as answered, you can update it with your comment if you want.